# apache vhosts https/ssl subdomain always redirected to main non-https page

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, https, vhosts

my vhosts configuration file looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName api.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/live/api/
    <Directory /var/www/example.com/live/api/>
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mycert.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/live/
<Directory /var/www/example.com/live/>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error-example.com-live.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

as soon as I try to access https://api.example.com I get redirected to http://www.example.com.
When I change the document root to /var/www/whatever-but-not-used-by-other-vhost it is working without any problems.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should have a .htaccess in the documentroot or a redirection made by a script based on the HTTP_HOST

Comment: Thanks. I have a .htaccess in both document roots, butn whatever I put in, I get redirected to [http://www.example.com](http://www.example.com). If I add a CustomLog to the first virualhost, it logs a 301 redirect, but I have no idea where it comes from.